# Remote EJB Access using the EJB client jar

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, weblogic, ejb-3.0

I have an EJB ear deployed to Weblogic. The EJB has some JMS queues setup which it sends out a message by design.
The client web application invoking the EJB is running on another JVM on the same machine (to mimic a remote call)

EJB Interface

```
@Remote
public interface MyLog {
    public void doSomething();
}
```

In the client,

Maven dependency includes the following. I'm using the ejb jar itself. How do I go about generating the ejb client jar and what's the difference between the two?

org.ihc.myLog
    myLog-ejb
    1.0
    jar

I'm using spring to lookup the ejb and I'm using the ejb jar (Not sure if I fully understand the difference between the ejb jar and the ejb-client jar).

```
<bean id="myLog" parent="MyEjbParent" lazy-init="false">
   <property name="jndiName" value="MyLog#org.ihc.My.MyLog"/>
   <property name="businessInterface" value="org.ihc.audit.AuditLog"/>
   <property name="lookup-home-on-startup" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

and I'm using Spring DI to wire myLog to the appropriate attribute of a class and performing my operations.

myLog.doSomething();

The problem is that when I try to deploy the web app that invokes the EJB, the deployment fails saying that the JMS queues aren't setup on the client Application server. I do not understand why the client applicaion server needs to have the JMS queues setup as they are already setup on the Weblogic server running the EJB instance. Shouldn't the client be just concerned about invoking the remote method and let the EJB do it's thing? Might be that my config is wrong or something else? Thanks.

Here is the error I get during deployment of the client web app that invokes the ejb

```
|Exception while loading the app : EJB Container initialization error
com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: JMS resource
not created : jms.mylog_queue
```

Answer (score 1):

Has your ejb client jar the ejbs with in it or the configuration files 
or does it contain just the Interface classes.
Seems that you client server also tries to initialize your beans which
indeed is not necessary.

Try to seperate client code from server code. Your client just needs to know
the remote interfaces and your client server needs all ejb-client dependencies
in order to invoke all that ejb remote --> rmi-iiop stuff.

UPDATE due to comment:

Create a seperate WEB Project. With just the dependencies it needs to invoke 
the remote EJBS. In this case the Remote Interfaces. 
If it is a Web Project than just put in the configurations which are
necessary for this WEB-Project and deploy it as a WAR File not as a JAR or EAR.

Comment: The client jar has all the EJB classes. It also has a META-INF folder with the ejb-jar.xml file. Should this be in the client jar at all? I think you are right that it is trying to initialize the EJB container itself which it shouldn't. How do I go about separating the client code from the server code. My configuration shouldn't trigger the creation of an EJB at all right?

Comment: here is the problem. Remove all configuration files or annotated ejb implementations. Because during the deployment it also tries to initialize the ejbs but the jms configuration does not exist within the client server so deployment fails.

Comment: Makes sense. But I do not have any annotations or ejb declarations in the client code. I have the spring config as mentioned to create to create an instance of the Business interface. I'm injecting that to a Spring managed bean. I'm using this injected instance to call the Business interface method. So it's puzzling me why the EJB creation is triggered when the client web app is deployed. I'm missing something sneaky!

Comment: If you deploy a package to  any JEE conform server the deployment process tries to resolve all configuration files which are located within the package. -> Hot deployment. What kind of server do you use for the client app.

Comment: I'm using Glassfish Full Edition for the client web app. "tries to resolve all configuration files which are located within the package". I'm trying to find which piece of my client code is triggering the initialization of the EJB.

Comment: what about META-INF/ejb-jar.xml. Yes and glassfish also contains a ejb-container.

Comment: I see the ejb-jar.xml file in the client jar. Should i be in there? It's generated by putting the <generateClient> tag in the maven EJB plugin.

Comment: Ahh you use maven for the generation. No it shouldn't be in there for the client. Because there the configuration is done for your EJBs. If the ejb-jar.xml file is found from the server than initialization is triggered.